# Not able to increment inside an array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to increment the count and write the values in an array `serialBuffer` in Python.
How can I increment the count value (initially 0)?

```
 if serialIndex < 200: 
     serialBuffer[serialIndex += 1] = serialData
  # i get this error         ^ ']' expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this on just one line. You'll have to split it up.

```
if serialIndex < 200: 
    serialBuffer[serialIndex] = serialData
    serialIndex += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, That helped me lot. would that be same for the function parameters.                                                                                                        `while serialBufferWalk < serialIndex:
 if self.SerialUnEscape(serialBuffer[serialBufferWalk += 1], serialDataLsb ):
   break`

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't work either. `a += b` is a [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), and statements can't appear inside expressions.

Comment: what woud be the best way to implement this second part of the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728934/trouble-understanding-pass-by-reference) which is in C#    `while (serialBufferWalk < serialIndex) {
        if (SerialUnEscape(serialBuffer[serialBufferWalk++], ref serialDataLsb)) {
            break;
                }
               }`

Comment: I guess you would just stick `serialBufferWalk += 1` after the `if` block. I'm not 100% confident in my C# ability, so I'm not totally sure.